# Two drawable to edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable

I have added drawables to both ends of edittext. When I click on right drawable, the left one disappears.
Basically the edittext is for password input.Icon lock and icon visibility(eye) are to the left and right of edittext respectivily.The right icon toggles as per visibility of password

Listener implementation for right drawable:

```
 etPassword.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (event.getRawX() >= (etPassword.getRight() - etPassword.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                        if (etPassword.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD) {
                            etPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                                    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                            etPassword.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_visibility_off_white_24dp, 0);
                            etPassword.setSelection(etPassword.getText().length());
                        } else {
                            etPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
                            etPassword.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_visibility_white_24dp, 0);

                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**xml**:

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_visibility_off_white_24dp"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_white_24dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary" />
```

**screen shots:**
[image]

The issue is on clicking visibility icon, the left drawable disappears,here's the screenshot
[image]

Comment: what is the problem >

Comment: right icon is for toggling of the show password and hide. what is the left icon is for ???

Comment: @Sagar Nayak added screenshots

Comment: so you dont want the lock icon to disappear after you click the eye ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding 0 for start|left icon position of EditText  `etPassword.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_visibility_off_white_24dp, 0);`

Add your lock_icon in start|left position of your EditText :

```
etPassword.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(lock_icon, 0, R.drawable.ic_visibility_off_white_24dp, 0);
```

Final code:

```
etPassword.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (event.getRawX() >= (etPassword.getRight() - etPassword.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                        if (etPassword.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD) {
                            etPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                                    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                            etPassword.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(lock_icon, 0, R.drawable.ic_visibility_off_white_24dp, 0);
                            etPassword.setSelection(etPassword.getText().length());
                        } else {
                            etPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
                            etPassword.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(lock_icon, 0, R.drawable.ic_visibility_white_24dp, 0);

                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```